# What is maximium resolution of a html page?

Tags: html, graphics, resolution

I have few question in this regard

1. When you create an internet page, does the program automatically create 75pdi?
2. Could we create 300DPI page could this be able communicate on internet ?
3. What is maximum DPI resolution you can get on a Web page?

Comment: DPI is a print term. The monitor display term is PPI (pixels per inch).

Comment: HTML doesn’t have a resolution. You rather mean images that are referenced in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Unless the entire web page is just an image file, web pages don't specify a resolution like that. HTML defines the layout and contents of the page, the video and printer drivers determine the resolution it is displayed or printed in.
2. Meaningless question, see #1.
3. See #2.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions (I'm presuming you're talking about images *on* a web page, rather than the web page itself, which is created in HTML, etc.)

1. You should create the image at 72dpi. Most programs with 'Save for web' functionality *should* convert the image to 72dpi, but you may need to do this yourself.
2. You could put a 300dpi image on the web and it should display correctly in pretty much all browsers (and should print at the correspondingly higher resolution), but this is a bad idea as it'll be much slower to load/render, will consume bandwidth, etc. As such, I'd *really* recommend sticking to 72dpi. If you want a high resolution version of an image, link to the raw image file or create a (resolution independent PDF or SVG, etc.)
3. As above, there's no maximum (although the web site's visitors machines will eventually grind to a halt attempting to decode an 'n' DPI image).

Answer (score 0):

Web displays graphics at 72dpi. If you make an image that is 300dpi, it's going to look much larger on the screen than was intended.

Answer (score 0):

DPI, be it 72 or 300, is only relevant when going to an output device like a printer, talking about DPI for web graphics is meaningless. On the web, all images are shown 1::1. A pixel of data in the image is a pixel of data on the screen.

You can use any DPI you want for a web image. It makes no difference in how it will be displayed.

**BUT** - if you are working towards the web you can no longer measure things in inches, centimeters of picas.  You need to start working with all dimensions in **pixels**.  If you are viewing your graphics in Photoshop, make sure your view is set to 100%. Then you'll be seeing the same thing that will be displayed in the browser.

Everyones browser is different, so a conservative estimate for a static page design is that your page content should be about 900 pixels or so wide. (People are used to scrolling down, so your page height can be whatever you want).